# The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.4, cachedrowset

i updated the UPSERT_DELETE_JOB_COUNTERS.
Now i think the "upsert" works with the new Query =) Or what do you think?

regards,
Peter

```
`private static final String UPSERT_DELETE_JOB_COUNTERS =
        "UPDATE rating.delete_job_counters SET delete_count = delete_count + ? WHERE fee_group_id = ? AND delete_job_id = ?; "+
        "INSERT INTO  rating.delete_job_counters(delete_job_id, fee_group_id, delete_count ) "+
        "SELECT ?, ? , ? " +
        "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM rating.delete_job_counters  WHERE fee_group_id = ? AND delete_job_id = ?); ";

@Override
public Boolean insertIntoDeleteStatistic(final CachedRowSet deletedEntries,
                                      Long deleteJobId,
                                      Transaction transaction) throws SQLException {
    boolean finish = true;
    if (deletedEntries.size() == 0) {
        return finish;
    }
    final Connection connection = transaction.getConnection();
    final Timer executeTimer = Timer.start("Insert took ");
    try {
        PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(UPSERT_DELETE_JOB_COUNTERS);
        while (deletedEntries.next()) {
            pstmt.setInt(1, deletedEntries.getInt(2));
            pstmt.setInt(2, deletedEntries.getInt(1));
            pstmt.setLong(3, deleteJobId);
            pstmt.setLong(4, deleteJobId);
            pstmt.setInt(5, deletedEntries.getInt(1));
            pstmt.setInt(6, deletedEntries.getInt(2));
            pstmt.setInt(7, deletedEntries.getInt(1));
            pstmt.setInt(8, deletedEntries.getInt(2));
            pstmt.execute();
        }...
```

`

Comment: I believe that `deleteCdr.getInt(2)` is the cause of the problem.  Are you sure that this cached result set actually has two columns available?

Comment: Not directly related to your issue, but you need to close `Statement` and `Connection`. Consider [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: ` UPDATE rating.delete_job_counters SET delete_count = delete_count + ? WHERE fee_group_id = ? AND delete_job_id = ?; 
            INSERT INTO  rating.delete_job_counters(delete_job_id, fee_group_id, delete_count ) 
            SELECT ?, ? , ? 
            WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM rating.delete_job_counters  WHERE fee_group_id = ? AND delete_job_id = ?); ` Is this query Ok? My first test was positive.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a parameterized `java.sql.PreparedStatement` with a `DO` statement.

Why don't you use [`INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) (available since PostgreSQL 9.5)?

For older versions of PostgreSQL, you'll probably have to code an “endless loop” like this pseudocode sample:

```
while (1) {
   INSERT ...
   if (insert went ok) break;
   UPDATE ...
   if (update changed one row) break;
}
```

Comment: We have PostgresSql 9.4 =( Do you have another idea?

Comment: I have edited the answer; I guess that's your only option.